# how to get delay working with setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: javascript, loops, timeout

I'm writing a snippet where JS displays all elements of an array as a counter, with random delay between beach of the steps in loop. However, `clearInterval` and `setInterval` don't seem to be working, as what I observe is that it keeps printing values forever in the browser console.

here's the code

```
var low = Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
var high = Math.floor(Math.random() * (95 - low + 1)) + low;
// generate array between low to high
heartbeats = Array.from( {length: 15}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low );
// sort it
heartbeats = heartbeats.sort((a,b) => a - b);
for (i in heartbeats){
   var randomPause = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000;
   theLooper = setInterval( function () {
   if (i == (heartbeats.length - 1) ) clearInterval(theLooper);
   console.log("Random Pause Is :: " + randomPause);
   console.log(heartbeats[i]);
   name1.innerHTML = heartbeats[i];
   },randomPause);
}
```

what I get instead of counter is a print of low then high instead of printing all the elements in the array. and console log keeps printing high forever

Comment: what is looper.length

Comment: That’s what setInterval does, keeps going over and over until you stop it.  And you are setting up 15 intervals.

Comment: `looper` was the original array, I put a snippet so that's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

In fact in your actual code you are not printing the values of the array after a respective delay one by one, you are just printing all the elements in a banch after the delay is passed.

And when you use `setInterval` the display won't stop, it will be displaying for ever.

**Solution:**

You need to use `setTimeout`, inside your `loop`, instead of `setInterval`, it will delay the instruction once, and make sure to increment the delay of the `setTimeout` function according to the iterated `index` use:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("index: " + i + " & element: " + el);
}, i * 1000);
```

**Demo:**

This is a Demo snippet:

```js
var low = Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 65 + 1)) + 65;
var high = Math.floor(Math.random() * (95 - low + 1)) + low;
// generate array between low to high
heartbeats = Array.from({
  length: 15
}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low);
// sort it
heartbeats = heartbeats.sort((a, b) => a - b);

heartbeats.forEach(function(el, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("index: " + i + " & element: " + el);
  }, i * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

I think your variable scope is causing the problem

**Solution**

Change `for(i in heartbeats)` to for `(let i in heartbeats)`, otherwise your `i` inside the setInterval callback will be always the last index of your array

Detailed doc can be found here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let